# Setting Routing in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

Help me please to set routing in Angular...

When no $location.path() the index.html and MainController must be load.
When $location.path() = @* , where * any name of object must be loaded the index2.html and myController.

Now it doesn't work:

```
 app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "index.html",
            controller: "MainController"
        })
        .when("/@*", {
            templateUrl: "index2.html",
            controller: "myController"
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If they're your only two routes, you can use [**otherwise(params)**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) :

> Sets route definition that will be used on route
>   change when no other route definition is matched.

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "index.html",
            controller: "MainController"
        })
        .otherwise({
            templateUrl: "index2.html",
            controller: "myController"
        });
});
```

Comment: when i'm trying to open directly `url.com/@object`... there is "Cannot GET /@object", what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Right I see, the problem is that you are not URL encoding the string. You can't use `@` in the URL. If it's neccessary then you must encode it to `%40` as explained [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)